# Как извлечь данные из индекса в колонки?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Свернул ее при помощи pivot_table:

```
data2 = pd.pivot_table(data1, index=['КАМ', 'Статус акции'], values='Объем', aggfunc='sum')
```

Однако теперь получается одна колонка с объемами, а данные сводной таблицы в индексе.

Как можно их разделить и сделать таблицу вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На будущее: приводите пожалуйста примеры данных и код в виде текста, а не в виде картинок. Текст/код из картинки невозможно скопировать и он не находится поиском... [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = data2.reset_index()
```

или одной командой:

```
data2 = (data1.pivot_table(index=['КАМ', 'Статус акции'], values='Объем', aggfunc='sum')
              .reset_index())
```